# upload large database file to the server

Tags: mysql

I have 5GB database that needs to be uploaded to phpmyadmin and that too on the shared server where i cannot access the shell.Is there any solution that can take lesser time to upload? Please do help me by providing the steps to upload the sql file. I have searched through internet but could not find an answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What exactly are the steps you have attempted so far?  What exactly isn't working as you expect?

Comment: I tried to import the database using PHPMYADMIN, but did not work.

Comment: sure webserver will never allow such big file to be uploaded.

Comment: actually we have hosted the website on shared server, so we do not have the access to shell

Comment: I am updating the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use phpmyadmin.

Assuming you have shell, upload the file and feed it directly to mysql command.

Your shell command will look like:

```
cat file.sql | mysql -uuser -ppassword database
```

or you can do gzipped file:

```
zcat file.sql.gz | mysql -uuser -ppassword database
```

Prior doing this check:

- database connection works (correct database, user and password)
- database is empty :)
- mysql max packet size is OK
- you have enough diskspace

---

*** UPDATE ***

You said you do not have shell access.

Then you have following options -

- **upload the file and contact support**, let they do it for you.
- **feed it remote**, `cpanel` have special menu where you can get remove access, other panels have same ability too.

in this case code will be executed on your computer and look like:

```
cat file.sql | mysql -uroot -phipopodil -hwebsite.com
```

or for windows:

```
/path/to/mysql -uroot -phipopodil -hwebsite.com < file.sql
```

- **do some "hack"** - feed it through `crontab`, `at` or via php system() command.

---

If you choose "hack" option, note following:

- php have max_execution_time - even if you set it to zero, there could be some limit "imposed" from hosting.
- usually hosts have limited mysql updates per hour.
- there could be some ulimit restrictions.
- if you execute feeding of 5 GB on shared server, server will slow down and administrator will check what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your database, you tagged it with 3 different database types, mysql, sql-server, and postgresql. I know mysql and postgresql have import features, although I'd be surprised if SQL Server didn't as well. You could import the database file via the command line instead of having to use phpmyadmin.

Incidentally, the phpmyadmin tool also has an import feature, but that again depends on the format of your database. If it's a compatible sql file, you could upload it to phpmyadmin and import it there, but I'd recommend the previous method I mentioned, upload it to your host, then use whatever database tool (mysqlimport for mysql, or if it's the result of a pg_dump command, you can just run:

```
psql <dbname> < <yourfile>
```

ie

```
psql mydatabase < inputfile.sql
```

Comment: I will not vote down, but you are giving instructions for postgres.

Comment: And I listed the mysqlimport command in the text, which is even more simple. It's moot anyway since the OP says they do not have shell access. I'd recommend your answer now anyway. Thanks.